# Wind Field freeze at frame 250. Where can it be changed?

Tags: animation, cache

I have setup a project of 250 frames with a flag and a wind force field. It works fine until I change the length of the project to 520 frames, then the flag is frozen after frame 250. There must be a simple way to change this. Thanks for any help. Regards, Daniel.

Comment: Have you modified the length of the wind field to 520 frames or just changed the length of the project?

Answer (score 5):

I pressume you are using cloth simulation for the flag. Go to the Cloth cache and modify the end to the number of frames you need.

[image]

Comment: To YoMismo, I just changed the length of the project. Where can I change the wind field to 520 frames?

Comment: To Cegaton, I have just changed the cloth cache to 520 frames and it works. Many thanks for your help. Kind regards,